# AngularJS parse date from facebook event

Tags: angularjs

Using Open Graph downloading the events from facebook.

I gets start event in format: `2015-10-24T18:00:00+0200`. How to use a separate date on the day, month and hour using angularjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a T format date and can just be used as a regular date object with

```
var d = new Date("2015-10-24T18:00:00+0200");
```

See the Date object reference for methods

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Ok, how to place result in `<p>{{ }}</p>` ?